# Caching http responses in iOS

Tags: ios, caching

I'm starting an iOS app that consume a Restful API.
I have control over that API and I'm confusing with the caching policies.

To begin, I only need caching a concrete resoruce, but the problem is that resource can change when I insert new record in the database.

Then, how can I tell to the application "Hey! Make the request only if there have been changes and if not, you get the data from the cache!"

I'm using AFNetworking to make requests..

Comment: You're requesting data and you only want to make a request if data on the remote application is changed? How is the app supposed to know if anything has changed?

Comment: Exactly, that is I want, but I don't know how do that! :(

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. There's no way for the client to magically know if things have changed on the server. You can have the client keep track of header values from the last request (such as `ETag` or `Last-Modified`). The server can then check this so it doesn't have to send back a full response. But without the client talking to the server in some way, it's impossible to know if data has changed.

Comment: Good answer! I'll investigate about last-modified param!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a decision on either server or client side and build your own protocol.

Example:
You could send the server JSON post request which contains the 'version' of the data you have in the app. On the server-side you will increment the version number each time the data gets refreshed. If the version number does not match at server-side, the server will respond with all new data, else the server responds JSON with 'up to date'

EDIT:
If you are looking for an HTTP response [saying that the data is not modified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection). This is done on server side. You'll have to implement [this in the server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html).

Comment: My intention is avoid to do a request if it is not necessary, maybe that is not possible...